# Find $4$ non-isomorphic graphs with $3$ vertex

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I want to prove that there are $4$ different and non-isomorphic graphs with $3$ vertex. I can come up with three of them: $\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}$ would be the first one, $\{2,3\}, \{3,1\}$ the second and $\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,1\}$ the third one. Could someone help me with the forth one?

Comment: The first two are isomorphic aren't they?  You should have graphs with 0,1,2, and 3 edges.

Comment: Is a graph with $0$ edges still a graph?

Comment: Yes.  There's nothing that says a graph has to have edges.  (There's some difference of opinion as to whether there's a graph with no vertices, however.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just consider $E_3,P_3,C_3$, and a graph with $V=\left\{v_1,v_2,v_3\right\}$ and only one edge, for instance, $\overline{v_1v_2}$.

If you're unfamiliar with the notations above, they refer to the empty, path, and cycle graphs of order 3 respectively.

Comment: I don't really understand what $P_3$ means. Is it the number of graphs that have $1$ or $2$ edges?

Comment: I said it in the second line of my answer, but I'll state it again:

$E_3$ is the empty graph of order 3, $P_3$ is the path graph of order 3, and $C_3$ is the cycle graph of order 3